# Calling a SOAP web service in a different domain using jQuery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, soap, cross-domain

I am implementing a web page purely with javaScript/jQuery (SSL enabled) which is to consume different services available from different domains.

I want to integrate a SOAP service which is not secured (with http) using jQuery ajax method as the need not to be reloaded.

I am getting security issue as well as cross domain control issue while trying this out.

Can you please suggest a better approach for the purpose as I couldn't find a proper way to do this anywhere?

Thanks in Advance,
idsTect

Comment: You would need to enable CORS on the server receiving the request, or return data in JSONP format. If you can't do either of those then it will not be possible to make this request client-side only.

Comment: Of course the receiving server doesn't support both and I don't have the control to change that as well.
I read something like implementing a proxy server or middle level server for the purpose in some post. Can you/anyone please let me know such workaround in detail or any other if available?